# Get the index of the selected item in longlistselector

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a long list selector

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="BTDevices"  SelectionChanged="BTDevices_SelectionChanged_1">
 <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="30" />
   </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
 </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

The function is defined as:

```
private void BTDevices_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
//here i want to get the index of the selected item
}
```

I tried the following line

```
int a = App.ViewModel.Items.IndexOf(sender as ItemViewModel);
```

But it always returns -1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the `SelectionChanged` event occurs, the `sender`parameter of the event handler represents the object that triggered this event. It is of type `Object`, but you can cast it to match your specific control type.

In this case, the `LongListSelector` :

```
var myItem = ((LongListSelector) sender).SelectedItem as Model;
```

(Model represents the type of data your control handles).

Afterwards, look for that item in the `ItemsSource` and retrieve its value :

```
var myIndex = ((LongListSelector) sender).ItemsSource.IndexOf(myItem);
```

You have named your control, so instead of `(sender as LongListSelector)`, you could use its name, `BTDevices`, but the code lines I wrote was intended to show you what's what with the `sender` object.

Alternatively (and this is a more elegant way), shown by bland, you could use the `EventArgs` for selection : `e.AddedItems[0]`

Comment: I follow your comments but the problem I am facing is like. e.g. I have full page of list view and only have 3 items. now when I select/press on blank area it gives -1. that is fine but when I select any item. it gives me index. that is also fine but the problem is after selecting any index I am clicking on blank space, still it gives the last selected index.

Comment: you should be able to get only valid indexes - that means 0+. I don;t know how you managed to get -1. Are you sure you have only 3 items in? Make a question, and give me the link.

Comment: To solve the problem of getting the selected index even on pressing on blank space try setting the selected item to null once you are done with it

Answer (score 1):

`sender` is going to be who sent the fact that this event occurred.  See [SelectionChangedEventArgs at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs.aspx) to know that you'll want to do `e.AddedItems[0]` if single-select list, or if multi-select list, you'll need to loop over it:

```
foreach(var item in e.AddedItems)
```