# WP8.1 Click event for child element in ListView ItemTemplate while ignoring ItemClick event

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I have a `ListView` with a DataTemplate. Inside the DataTemplate I have a clickable image

```
 <Image x:Name="likeImg" Tapped="likeButtonPressed" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="20"  Source="{Binding likedImage}"  Visibility="{Binding userID, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=HideForMyUser}}"/>
```

This event fires perfectly when clicked.

I added an `ItemClick` event handler to the `ListView` (and `IsItemClickEnabled` true of course) so that when an item is clicked, I want to navigate to a new page EXCEPT when the `likeImg` is clicked. When I click the `likeImg` both events fire.  Is there any way to ignore the ItemClick event when the image is tapped?

Comment: you got any solution for this ?

Comment: No I never found a solution for this. If you found the question useful and clear, perhaps up-voting this question may bring more attention to it.

Comment: Finally i have ended up by doing like this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851105/how-to-determine-which-child-element-of-a-listview-item-was-clicked). This works well for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the `SelectionMode` and `IsItemClickEnabled` of ListView and your child control (Image in your case) event should fire.

Below are the ListView Properties you should set.

```
SelectionMode="None"

IsItemClickEnabled="False"
```